# Execute powerShell command with r and shedule with Windows task sheduler?

Tags: r, powershell

I wrote an R script to copy a few files from one folder to another on an MS SQL server. The script executes a PowerShell command (Copy-Item) and copies the files if the files have the right names. If I start the script in R, RStudio or by using the bat file the script works. If I try to run the script resp. the bat file via the windows task scheduler the files will not be copied.

I tried to change the settings in the schedule without any success. Maybe the task scheduler needs a different path to copy the files because I connect to a network path on another client but I am confused that there is such a different behavior between starting the batch manually and form scheduler both with the same user credentials.

## Copy files with PowerShell command

```
ps_command <- paste('Copy-Item -Path ', "'" ,"X:\\InputDATA\\USAGE ACCOUNTING\\25 Webservice\\Cloud\\", Files[i], "'" , " " ,"-Destination",  ' ', "'" ,"X:\\InputDATA\\USAGE ACCOUNTING\\25 Webservice\\VIN", "'" ,sep = "") 

system(paste("powershell -command ", ps_command))
```

I don't find any error messages in the scheduler history but the job will be marked as completed just after I have started it. The job should normally run at least 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the problem in my script. It seems that the windows scheduler can not access network directories of a user so I changed the path and add the server name instead of the network directory:

"//servername/InputDATA/USAGE ACCOUNTING/25 Webservice/Cloud/"